# Redirect to %5c after submitting in django

Tags: python, django

I used **django.contrib.auth.views.login** for login page.

But it cause 404 error after redirecting by successful login.

following is error message:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/login/%5C
```

and following is html code:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Username or password is not correct. Try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">User name :</label>{{ form.username }}</p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password :</label>{{ form.password }}</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="\"/>
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

I don't know why login page redirect to **"./%5c"**, not **"."**

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%5c` represent a backslash (`\`).

```
>>> urllib.unquote('%5c')
'\\'
```

That comes from the following `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="\"/>
                                        ^
```

Now, you know whether to change.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ascii character coding.

http://grox.net/utils/encoding.html

%5cindicates \ . You have given a hidden element with value . This is where the redirection come from